# Downloading Many Images with Python Requests and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, image, multiprocessing, python-requests

I'm attempting to download a few thousand images using Python and the multiprocessing and requests libs. Things start off fine but about 100 images in, everything locks up and I have to kill the processes. I'm using python 2.7.6. Here's the code:

```
import requests
import shutil
from multiprocessing import Pool
from urlparse import urlparse

def get_domain_name(s):
    domain_name = urlparse(s).netloc 
    new_s = re.sub('\:', '_', domain_name)  #replace colons
    return new_s

def grab_image(url):
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=2)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        img_name = get_domain_name(url)
        with open(IMG_DST + img_name + ".jpg", 'wb') as outf:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, outf)
        del response

def main():                                        
    with open(list_of_image_urls, 'r') as f:                 
        urls = f.read().splitlines()                                                             
    urls.sort()                                    
    pool = Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=2)   
    pool.map(grab_image, urls)                     
    pool.close()                                   
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: After changing the multiprocessing import to multiprocessing.dummy to use threads instead of processes I am still experiencing the same problem. It seems I'm sometimes hitting a motion jpeg stream instead of a single image, which is causing the associated problems. In order to deal with this issue I'm using a context manager and I created a FileTooBigException. While I haven't implement checking to make sure I've actually downloaded an image file and some other house cleaning, I thought the below code might be useful for someone:

```python
class FileTooBigException(requests.exceptions.RequestException):
    """File over LIMIT_SIZE"""


def grab_image(url):
    try:
        img = ''
        with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=4)) as response:
            if response.status_code == 200:
                content_length = 0
                img_name = get_domain_name(url)
                img = IMG_DST + img_name + ".jpg"
                with open(img, 'wb') as outf:
                    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
                        outf.write(chunk)
                        content_length = content_length + CHUNK_SIZE
                        if(content_length > LIMIT_SIZE):
                            raise FileTooBigException(response)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
    except FileTooBigException:
        os.remove(img)
        pass
```

And, any suggested improvements welcome!

Comment: Do you get any errors/warnings when it locks up? Have you done any debugging to see if you can figure out where it's locking up? Is it locking up on the same images constantly?

Comment: Is the process still using any CPU when it hangs?  How much memory has it allocated?  Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit?  Is it creating the files up until it locks up?  Is it leaving any unusual garbage, such as 0-byte files?  How much disk space do you have left when it locks up?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in using `multiprocessing` for I/O concurrency. In network I/O the thread involved just waits most of the time doing nothing. And *Python threads are excellent for doing nothing.* So use a **threadpool**, instead of a processpool. Each process consumes a lot of resouces and are unnecessary for I/O bound activities. While threads share the process state and are exactly what you are looking for.